# How to change css using document.getElementsByClassName in typescript

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname

I want to set style top for some elements using typescript

```
for(var i=0; i< document.getElementsByClassName('calendar-event').length; i++){
        document.getElementsByClassName('calendar-event')[i].style.top = 50*i;
    }
```

This returns error Property 'style' does not exist on type element. How to make this work in typescript??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use setAttribute as below

```
let elemets = document.getElementsByClassName('calendar-event');

for(var i=0; i< elements.length; i++){
   var div = elements[i]
   div.setAttribute("style","top:"+50*i+"px");
}
```

Comment: Why would you not fix the code so as not to call `getElementsByClassName` over and over again/

Comment: removed the duplication.